# Rails simple navigation how to style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the simple navigation gem to create some "simple" navigation for my website.

I already have created a tabbed menu with CSS, JQUERY & HTML.

The only problem is creating the exact same CSS and HTML with simple navigation.

Here is my HTML that I am trying to create with simple navigation:

```
<ul id="ulmenu">

<li class="topmenuli" id="menufirst">
<a href="#" class="">Frontpage<span id="frontpage"></span></a>
<ul id="submenu" style="display: none;">
  <li><a style="font-weight:bolder;text-decoration:underline;background:url(../images/menua.png) no-repeat center bottom;" href="#" class="">Submenu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="">Submenu 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="topmenuli">
<span style="display:block;" id="pets"></span>
<a href="#">Pets</a>
<ul style="display:none;" id="submenu">
  <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li>Submenu 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

My simple navigation config file:

```
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|

    primary.item :frontpage, 'frontpage', root_url, :id => 'menufirst', :class => 'topmenuli'
    primary.item :domain, 'Pets', domain_path do |sub_nav|
      # Add an item to the sub navigation (same params again)
      sub_nav.item :dogs, 'Dogs', dogs_path
    end
  end
```

The output:

```
<ul><li id="menufirst" class="topmenuli selected simple-navigation-active-leaf"><a class="selected" href="http://localhost:3000/"><span>Frontpage</span></a></li>
<li id="petes"><a href="/pets"><span>Pets</span></a></li></ul>
```

Not quite as my HTML. The submenus are not showed. I also tried to use highligt but then the breadcrumb navigation is totally wrong.

How do I create my HTML menu with simple navigation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to change attributes on your `<ul>` container, use (for example) :

```
primary.item :domain, 'Pets', domain_path do |sub_nav|
  sub_nav.dom_id = 'some_submenu_id'
  sub_nav.dom_class = 'some_submenu_class'
  sub_nav.item :dogs, 'Dogs', dogs_path
  # add any more items you want
end
```

to change attributes on your `<li>` elements :

```
primary.item :domain, 'Pets', domain_path, :class => 'my_class', :id => 'my_id' # etc.
```

it is also possible to provide a custom `id` attribute generator (as stated in [the documentation](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/wiki/Styling) ):

```
navigation.id_generator = Proc.new {|key| "my-prefix-#{key}"}
```

as to your `style` attributes, i don't know if simple_navigation handles this, but all you have to do is to create some minimal css selectors:

```
.block
{
  display: block;
}

.container
{
  margin: 1em;
}
```

...  and associated classes :

```
<div class="block container">I will be displayed as a block and have a 1em margin</div>
```

Comment: I used <%= render_navigation(:expand_all => 'true') %> instead of <%= render_navigation %> and wrote the span tags in the name.

Comment: To add a class/id to the main `<ul>`, you could use `primary.dom_id = 'some_menu_id'
`

Answer (score 1):

The right way to add class for <li> and <a>:

```
primary.item :domain, 'Pets', domain_path, :html => {:class => "my_li_class"}, :link_html => {:class => "my_a_class"}
```

See [Official Simple Navigation FAQ](https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: This is promising. I see this documented in the FAQ you quote, but I cannot get it to work.  The generated HTML always has `<li link_html="{:class=>"my_a_class"}" id="domain">`

Any idea what is wrong?